# How to use username as a string in model in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to use the username of the account in which my django is running as a string to load the model fields specific to that username. I have created a file 'survey.py' which returns a dictionary and I want the keys as the fields.
How can I get the username as string?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField
from survey_a0_duplicate import details, analysis                                                                           
import ast

class HomeForm1(models.Model):
    user= models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)



    details.loadData(survey_name = user)#<=====This loads the data for specific user<======

    global f1
    f1=analysis.getQuestion(in_json=False)#<====We get the dictionary here<========                      

    d=list(f1.keys())


    ###################assign the filters####################################################### 
    for k in d:
        q=list(f1[k].keys())
        q.sort()
        choices=tuple(map(lambda f: (f,f),q))
        locals()[k]=MultiSelectField(max_length=1000,choices=choices,blank=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None:
            self.user= self.user.username
        super(HomeForm1,self).save(*args,**kwargs)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: You are mixing a lot of concepts here. You likely should *not* write procedural logic at the class level (only in a very limited number of cases that holds). Furthermore a model is *not* a form. A model deals with how your domain looks like, and how you store it in the database. A form deals with how you interact with the user. Finally a model is request-unaware, so normally it does not know anything about what is manipulating the model, and what the user is.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you write Django code. Global variables are a bad idea anyway, but you **must not** use them in a multi-user, multi-process environment like Django. You will immediately have thread-safety issues; you must not do it.

Not only is there an explicit global in the code you have shown, there is clearly one inside `survey_a0_duplicate` - since `details.loadData()` does not actually return anything but you then "get the dictionary" from `analysis.getQuestion`. You must remove the globals from both locations.

Also, your save method is totally wrong. You have the user relationship; why would you overwrite it with the username? That not only makes no sense, it specifically destroys the type of the field that you have set. Just don't do it. Remove the entire save method.

But you need to stop messing about with choices at class level. That is never going to work. If you need to dynamically set choices, do in in a form, where you can customise the `__init__` method to accept the current user and build up the choices based on that.

Comment: could you tell me where I can find a method to customise the __init__ .py to accept the current user?

Comment: As both Willem and I said, that would need to be done in a form, not in the model.